# Как изменить размер UIView, на которой находится UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Есть UIView, на которой находится UILabel, и свойство numberOfLines установлено в ноль. Как изменять размер UIView, если текст в лейбл будет больше чем одна строка.

```
let someView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("foo", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! foo 
someView.label.text = text
```

Comment: Используй не UIView, а UIScrollView, таким образом текст можно будет проскролить. Вот пример на [видео](http://goo.gl/Gaez5N).

Comment: @AndriiMoisol Мне не нужно его скролить, это должен быть лейбл, который расширяет контейнер

Comment: Используй constraints

Answer (score 0):

Задайте констрейнты для вью (или фрейм), затем задайте констрейнты для лейбла, а потом в зависимости от того сколько линий, увеличивайте нужный констрейнт(или height для фрейма).